# How to render ink drop volumetric with transparent background?

Tags: rendering, export, transparency

Working on a very rudimentary animation of a red ink drop. I'm using a volume absorption node to give the ink the look that I want, but I need to export this animation as a PNG which can be composited against footage in After Effects, and when I switch the white world to transparent, the ink drop turns black. How can I render out the ink without a white background? I haven't had any luck using a light instead. The ink remains black.

Any advice is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a workaround you can render it as a EXR sequence, so you will have one alpha pass to use for the compositing in after effect

Answer (score 0):

Let the world stay white. Just go to your *Render Properties > Film > Transparent* and click the check box.